# set a css inline property based on a ng-model value

Tags: angularjs

I wonder if possible to do something like this;

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="color">


 <p style="color: {{ color }}">something goes here</p>
```

so the text changes its color as soon as new value is placed in the input.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) for that

```
<input type="button" value="set color" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
<input type="button" value="set background" ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'blue'}">
<input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myStyle={}">
<br/>
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
<pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
```

Comment: basically I need the to be on a text input, I would need something like on change, which is the part when I get ostl

Comment: it doesnt matter which type of input you are using, you can also use <input type="text"  ng-model="someVar">